# Use of imagettfbbox() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Im right now working on a new app and i need to calculate a string length in pixel with specified font. I decided to use imagettfbbox() in laravel.

But when i use this its tell me that the function doenst exist? Anyone else had this problem?

```
public function checkTitle() {
    $title = $this->html->find('title',0)->innertext;
    $test = imagettfbbox(18, 0, 'arial.tff', $title);
}
```

ERROR:
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\imagettfbbox()

Hope someone can figure this out? :)

- Thanks

Comment: Is [`freetype support`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php#refsect1-function.imagettfbbox-notes) included in your php installation?

Comment: GD Support enabled in my phpinfo

Answer (score 0):

Noticed GD was installed but not FreeType :) Thanks for the help.